# Showing errors of jsp files in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, ide

Does IntelliJ IDEA support highlights errors of JSP files in the project window like Netbeans or Eclipse?

If it does, how to enable it?

You can look here and see what I mean

[image]